# Showing H is a normal subgroup by calculating left and right coset

Tags: group-theory

If $G = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} a,b\in (\mathbb{R}) : a \neq 0$)

and assume G is a group under matrix multpication

Prove that H = ($\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: t\in\mathbb{R}$) is a normal subgroup of G

I'm meant to show that H is a normal subgroup by showing that the left coset is equal to the right coset.

So far I have shown the following:

take $g=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

then 
$gH=\begin {pmatrix}a &at+b \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$

and take $g'=\begin{pmatrix} a' & b' \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

then $Hg'=\begin{pmatrix} a' & b'+t \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

I don't quite understand how $gH=Hg'$

Comment: They are equal as sets, it's not true that $\forall h\in H$, $gh=hg$.

Comment: So how do I finish this proof off then? I don't understand what you mean by they are equal as sets

Comment: He means that $gh=h'g$ for some $h'\in H$

Comment: So can I just simply say gH=Hg' as the sets are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me solve the problem the way you asked: proving that every left coset is a right coset.

---

Given $g=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ one must prove that $gH=Hg$ (introducing an additional symbol $g'$ is wrong). Your question correctly describes the general format of matrices in the sets $gH$ and $Hg$, so I'll work with that.

Consider $M$ in $gH$, and so there exist $t$ such that
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}a & at+b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in gH
$$
For $M$ to be in $H g$, one must find $t'$ so that
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}a & b+t' \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in Hg
$$
Three of the matrix entries are already equal, so we must simply find $t'$ so that 
$$at+b = b+t'
$$
That equation is easily solved: $t'=at$, which proves that $M \in Hg$.

The reverse inclusion $Hg \subset gH$ is proved similarly.

---

However, despite the definition of a normal subgroup $H < G$ being

- "every left coset of $H$ is a right coset of $H$"

and despite the utility of that definition in *applying* normality, for purposes of *proving* normality it is almost always easier  to work from the equivalent statement

- "$gHg^{-1}=H$ for every $g \in G$"

or even easier

- "$g H g^{-1} \subset H$ for every $g \in G$"

So, given $g = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $h = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, I simply do a calculation
$$g h g^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a^{-1} & -b/a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & at+b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a^{-1} & -b/a \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & at \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
And this is obviously in $H$, by setting $t'=at$.

Comment: How do I show that given a,b,t that the system can be solved for a',b',t'?

Comment: Isn't a'=a?  or do you mean (b'+t' -b)/t

Comment: oh then I don't have any clue on how to solve this